# How to get the child div of parent div with some test id using react testing library?

Tags: react-testing-library

i want to get the div element within parent element with some test-id

what i am trying to do?

I have a parent div with test-id "parent-2" and it has a div element within it that has text Remove.

i want to retreive this Remove div element. also there is multiple Remove div elements. something like below

```
<div data-test-id="parent-1">
    <div>Remove</div>
</div>
<div data-test-id="parent-2">
    <div>Remove</div>
</div>
<div data-test-id="parent-3">
    <div>Remove</div>
</div>
```

So in the above html code i want to click Remove div from div with parent test-id = "parent-2"

I have tried to do like below

```
utils.fireEvent.click(getByText('Remove'));
```

this throws error found multiple instances of Remove.

I tried also this
    utils.fireEvent.click(getByTestId('parent-2').children[0];

this works. but this accesses the first child of the parent. however wanted to be more specific with the query.

So how can i fix this such that i can click Remove div belong to div of test-id "parent-2"

thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

react-testing-library queries return DOM nodes, so you can use DOM APIs on top. You need something like this :

```js
utils.fireEvent.click(getByTestId('parent-1').querySelector('div'));
```

querySelector takes a CSS selector, so you could give your inner div a class and be more specific :

```js
utils.fireEvent.click(getByTestId('parent-1').querySelector('.myClass'));
```

see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector,
- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall

Answer (score 15):

I think the more organic approach here is to use `within`,

```
import {within} from '@testing-library/dom';

const secondParent = getByTestId('parent-2');
utils.fireEvent.click(within(secondParent).getByText('Remove'));
```

Here is the docs description of `within`,

> within (an alias to getQueriesForElement) takes a DOM element and binds it to the raw query functions, allowing them to be used without specifying a container. It is the recommended approach for libraries built on this API and is used under the hood in React Testing Library and Vue Testing Library.

Reference:

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/

Answer (score 1):

i would offer two possible solution.

**solution #1**

using `childNodes` on the selected DOM element.

that will be useful if you have one element or multiple elements

```
utils.fireEvent.click(getByTestId('parent-1').childNodes[0]);
```

**solution #2**

using `getByText` cusom matching function within the selected DOM element.

that will be useful if you need to select the desiered element by its content or tag element.

```
utils.fireEvent.click(
 within(getByTestId('parent-1')).getByText((content, element) => content.includes('Remove')
);
```

or:

```
utils.fireEvent.click(
 within(getByTestId('parent-1')).getByText((content, element) => element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div'
);
```